# Issue matching Type of function to one defined in signature

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have a structure to define lazily evaluated sequences which are defined as

```
datatype 'a seq = Cons of 'a option * (unit -> 'a seq)
```

and I have a function map() that maps a function of type ('a->'b) to the values in the sequence.

```
val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a seq -> 'b seq
```

However when I define the function, it doesn't match the type provided by the signature, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it match. Everything I tried either didn't affect it or made it even worse.

```
fun map fu (Cons(NONE, f)) = map fu (f())
  | map fu (Cons(SOME x, f)) = Cons(fu(x), fn () => map(fu) (f()))
```

Which gives me the error type in structure doesn't match signature

```
  spec:   ('a -> 'b) -> 'a ?.Seq.seq -> 'b ?.Seq.seq
  actual: ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a ?.Seq.seq -> 'b ?.Seq.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

One AH moment later and I think I solved the issue. I finally realized that it was being typed that way because Cons took an option, and for some reason despite looking at it so many times I didn't even think of that. Here's my solution

```
fun map fu (Cons(NONE, f)) = map fu (f())
  | map fu (Cons(SOME x, f)) = Cons(SOME(fu(x)), fn () => map(fu) (f()))
```